# Android studio projects won't start in sync process

Tags: android, android-studio

yesterday all was ok,

that error i can find in event log

> Gradle sync failed: Could not run JVM from the selected JDK.      Please
>   ensure JDK installation is valid and compatible with the current OS
>   (Windows 10 10.0, amd64).         If you are using embedded JDK, please make
>   sure to download Android Studio bundle compatible         with the current
>   OS. For example, for x86 systems please choose a 32 bits download
>   option. (30 ms)

Comment: Did you check the selected JDK?

Comment: i already even reinstal it, but fix comes unexpected, as i update AS to last version and all start working